# Wordpress Query based on random taxonomy

Tags: query-posts

I am banging my head to get this solved, would appreciate if any one can help

***The scenario is,***

- I have a WordPress site related to books.
- I have a custom taxonomy named "History Books" sluged as "history_books".
  under this particular taxonomy, I have many history books(terms).
- under my /assets/images/books folder, I have all the images related to specific booked (terms) i.e terms_hsb1.jpg

  ***What I want is,***
- I need to run a RANDOM query based on my custom taxonomy "    history_books", which should return a randomly selected term.
- Then I need to show the related image for that specific term.
- Total count of that terms
- A direct link to the term archive page.

  ***In Second Step,***
- I want to show five post related to that specific term.

I was trying many combinations, but nothing worked. Lately, I tried this code

```
            <?php 
            $sugarquery = new WP_Query();
            $sugarquery->query( array( 'taxonomy' => 'history_books', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1 ) );
            while( $sugarquery ->have_posts() ) : $sugarquery ->the_post();
            ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            <?php
            $product_terms = wp_get_object_terms('history_books');
            if(!empty($product_terms)){
            if(!is_wp_error( $product_terms )){
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($product_terms as $term){
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'history_books').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>'; 
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            }
            }

            endwhile; ?>
```

I does query from specific tax, and returns one random post, but after that nothing happens.

Please help me, what is the better way to get this done?

BR

Comment: The `showpost` argument is deprecated. Use `posts_per_page` instead.

Comment: thank you, but that is just a sample code, I need a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$all_books = get_terms( 'history_books' );           // Get all history book terms.
$rand_book = $all_books[ array_rand( $all_books ) ]; // Select one at random.
$related = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'history_books',
                'terms'    => array( $rand_book->term_id ),
            )       
        )
    )
);

?>

<h3>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $rand_book ) ?>">
        <img src="/path/to/images/terms_hsb<?php echo $rand_book->term_id ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $rand_book->name ) ?>" />
        <?php echo esc_html( $rand_book->name ) ?>
    </a> (<?php echo $rand_book->count ?>)
</h3>

<?php if ( $related ) : ?>

    <ul class="related">
        <?php foreach ( $related as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ) ?>

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>

<?php endif ?>
```